# WPF Adorner not being drawn outside of UIElement borders

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building usage tutorial for app and trying to guide user through steps by pointing to correct options and explaining them and when he successfully completes current step, it should automatically move on to next. After some research I found out about Adorners and thought they would be most suitable for that and have built classes based on tutorial **found on link**:

http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/07/12/wpf-adorners-part-4-ndash-simple-and-powerful-system-for.aspx

Adorners act as they should on main window, but when accessing some option from menu, I get something like this:

[image]

So, adorners are not rendered outside of adorned element. If I understood correctly, correct me if I am wrong, they have their own layer and should be rendered on top of UIElement? I know they can't be rendered outside of MainWindow, but is it the same with elements inside of it ?

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
   <Window x:Class="_2EV.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:tutorial="clr-namespace:_2EV.tutorial"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_2EV"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"  Height="750" Width="430" MaxHeight="750" MaxWidth="430" Closing="Window_Closing">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="step1">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                    <Grid Margin="5 10 0 0">
                        <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Margin="0 20 0 0"/>
                        <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" Data="M 25 20 L 20 0 33 20" Margin="0 1 0 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Press new to acces add menu" Margin="5 25 0 0"/>
                </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="step2">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

                <Grid  Margin="5 10 0 0">
                    <Rectangle Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" RadiusX="6" RadiusY="6" Margin="0 20 0 0"/>
                    <Path Stroke="Black" Fill="Yellow" Data="M 25 20 L 20 0 33 20" Margin="0 1 0 0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Press classroom to acces new classrom menu" Margin="5 25 0 0"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>


    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock ="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <MenuItem Header="_Tables" InputGestureText="F2" Click="MenuItem_Click_4">
                <MenuItem Header="_Classrooms" Click="MenuItem_Click" ToolTip="Classrooms table, add, edit, delete classrooms"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Course" Click="MenuItem_Click_1" ToolTip="Courses table, add, edit, delete courses"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Software" Click="MenuItem_Click_2" ToolTip="Software table, add, edit, delete software"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Subject" Click="MenuItem_Click_3" ToolTip="Subjects table, add, edit, delete subjects"/>
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem x:Name="_NewHeader" Header="_New" Click="step1_start" tutorial:Adorners.Template="{StaticResource step1}">
                <MenuItem Header="_Classroom"  ToolTip="Classrooms table, add, edit, delete classrooms" Name="AddClassroomMenuItem"  Click="AddClassroomMenuItem_Click" tutorial:Adorners.Template="{StaticResource step2}"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Course"  ToolTip="Courses table, add, edit, delete courses" Name="AddCourseMenuItem" Click="AddCourseMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Software"  ToolTip="Software table, add, edit, delete software" Name="AddSoftwareMenuItem" Click="AddSoftwareMenuItem_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Subject"  ToolTip="Subjects table, add, edit, delete subjects" Name="AddSubjectMenuItem" Click="AddSubjectMenuItem_Click"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <Button x:Name="tutorialButton" Content="Tutorial" Width="75" Click="startTutorial"/>
        </Menu>
        <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <DockPanel>

            </DockPanel>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: you are being constrained by the element in which you attached.  Can you give us more code?  Windows / Menu / Placement of your Adorner?

Comment: So it is not possible at all to extend it over the border of adorned element ? Sure, i attached whole MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Most likely that's because you use it inside a popup. Popup is like separate window, it's not part of main window visual tree, so you cannot extend your adorner outside that popup window (menu dropdown).

Comment: What do you suggest as the solution ?

Comment: @Lupus, well, you would need to implement your own version of a balloon using Popup as a basis. Although, that would require quite some work to do all the plumbing with regard to positioning (and perhaps tracking) of the balloon popup. Alternatively, you could look for libraries which provide functionality you sought. One possible candidate for such a library could be this one: https://github.com/ControlzEx/ControlzEx or this one: https://toastspopuphelpballoon.codeplex.com/. For more alternatives, Google is your friend... ;)

Comment: Probably the best solution is to use library, thanks a lot everyone, particularly @elgonzo for the suggestions!